# Keyboard not working in one user account

Tags: windows, laptop, keyboard, windows-8.1

My friend have a strange problem. Few weeks ago, he just bought a new keyboard for his laptop, because it's internal keyboard is broken. But recently, his new keyboard suddenly not working in his laptop. So, I helped him to fix it.

First, I want to ensure his keyboard is functioning properly. I tried to connect his keyboard into my laptop, it worked properly. Even, I tried to connect it into his Android phone, it also worked. So, **it is not keyboard's hardware problem.**

Second, I want to ensure the keyboard's driver is properly working. I opened Device Manager and found that new keyboard's driver is properly installed and working. I tried to update the driver, but it's no use. So, **it is not keyboard's driver problem.**

Third, I want to ensure if it was Windows problem. I checked keyboard setting, it's layout ("English (US)", as expected), boot into Safe Mode, still no use. I tried to boot externally into Windows installation recovery with USB media, and open Command Prompt to test the keyboard, and shockingly it worked. So, *I suspected at first that it is Windows problem.*

**Edit:** And yes, the new keyboard also worked in BIOS ("UEFI Firmware" to be exact).

But then, I tried to boot normally into Windows in the laptop, and then I log out from his user account, shockingly (again) it worked. So, **(I guess) it is not Windows' problem.** Then, I tried to log into guest account just to test the keyboard, and the keyboard is worked properly. So, **I suspected the problem is in his user account.**

Does anyone know how to fix this particular issue? I cannot find the solution anywhere in the Internet yet, and it is confuses me because this is the first time I found this issue.

Any answers will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: its possible that, whatever the problem is, either also disables the internal keyboard, or the internal keyboard becomes in a state that makes the external keyboard also stops working. you should try to see if at the places where the external keyboard is working, if the internal keyboard is working there too. Could be a program they installed or a virus/malware/keylogger issue.

Comment: What is the keyboard interface? wireless/bt or cabled? Also, make and model

Comment: @LPChip the internal keyboard is broken (all keys are unresponsive), so I cannot sure. however, the external keyboard was working before now. about virus/malware/keylogger, i do not know though, Windows Defender seems working fine all time.

Comment: So this keyboard can operate via a USB cable, OR bluetooth? Do you have make and model

Comment: @JohnnyVegas both worked; he did use USB for pc, and BT for android (he did not use android for writing though). about make/model, there is no any, probably another chinese product (no offense).

Comment: @JohnnyVegas he did use USB for Windows

Comment: The model/make is quite important as your problem is quite unusual - Is there a label on the bottom of the keyboard? Dual interface keyboards (BT & USB) are quite rare and sometimes require drivers

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I found a sticker -- "Grotic"? maybe that supposed to be a brand (why the sticker is so small tho?). anyway, i thought driver is not a problem, since it worked driver-less before, also it worked in BIOS.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas also, i mentioned it works properly in my laptop, driverlessly.

Comment: If it's caused by user profile corruption, perhaps the solution would be to move everything to a new profile.

Comment: @harrymc that could be a final solution if no other workarounds worked

Comment: Profile corruption problems are very hard to analyze. You could try to change and set again the keyboard layout used by the user in *Settings > Time & Language > Language*.

Comment: @harrymc i tried. it still not working

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I have found the cause of problem: Sticky Keys and Filter Keys.

These Ease of Access "features" were accidentally activated unbeknownst to him. I turned off these and the keyboard is working fine again.